# Webdeploy error: "Error: Source (contentPath) and destination (appHostConfig) are not compatible for the given operation"

Tags: iis, webdeploy, microsoft-web-deploy, applicationhost

By using the example here, we are trying to export a site from 2008 server and import it in 2016 server.

**Export (in 2008):**

```
msdeploy.exe -verb:sync -source:apphostconfig="Default Web Site" -dest:package=c:\dws.zip
```

**Import (in 2016):**

```
msdeploy.exe -verb:sync -source:package=c:\dws.zip -dest:apphostconfig="Default Web Site"
```

This works in my VM. However, when we try to do it in the actual server, import fails with this error:

> Error: Source (contentPath) and destination (appHostConfig) are not
>   compatible for the given operation.

[image]

Export command is somehow converting the package to `contentPath` provider. Additionally, even though this document says that the `package` provider can be combines with other providers, we still get the **not compatible** error above.

Any ideas?

Comment: if a Web site exists in the ApplicationHost.config file that you specify for the source but not in the ApplicationHost.config file that you specify for the destination, the Web site will be created in the destination ApplicationHost.config file. You can specify different values for the source and destination paths (for example, the source site can be "Default Web Site" and the destination can be "My Site"). However, the source and destination paths must be configured at the same level; that is, a Web site path must synchronize to a Web site path, and a server path to a server path.

Comment: you could directly try to use the web deploy GUI interface.